# javascript - dojo 1.8 tabcontainer not rendering completely

Tags: javascript, dojo

As a programming student, I've been trying to acquaint myself with Dojo for a javascript project.  In my jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/brennonbrimhall/BdpFm/3/, I've copied several other examples of dijit widgets, but I've been unable to resolve the tabs.  It seems to me that it's only rendering halfway, as compared to the examples here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/layout/TabContainer.html

Are there any obvious mistakes I'm making?

Comment: mistakes of what exactly? it is not enirely clear what the question is

Comment: The tabs don't aren't highlighted on focus or once it's in an active state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the stylesheet which is equivalent with the version of framework.

See the tab 'Managed Resources' for CSS stylesheet paths

http://jsfiddle.net/BdpFm/4/